# Strange behavior of CoreData when deleting objects

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

I try to build simple bezier curves editor. Model and code below.
When I'm trying to delete *node.bcpInData* or *node.bcpOutData* only *node.originData* is deleted, witch has no sense at all.

This is my model:
[image]

Here is *delete:* method:

```
-(void) delete:(id)sender {

    [undoManager beginUndoGrouping];
    [points willChangeValueForKey:@"arrangedObjects"];

    NSMutableArray * nodesToDelete = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (TPPointData * pointData in points.selectedObjects) {


        NSLog(@"PointData %@", pointData);
        NSLog(@"PointData.node = %@", pointData.node);
        TPNode * node = pointData.node;

        if (pointData == pointData.node.originData) {
            //delete everything
            [nodesToDelete addObject:pointData.node];
            if (pointData.node.bcpInData!=nil)   {
                NSLog(@"deleting bcpInData: %@", pointData.node.bcpInData);
                [moc deleteObject:pointData.node.bcpInData];
                pointData.node = nil;
            }
            if (pointData.node.bcpOutData!=nil) {
                NSLog(@"deleting bcpOutData: %@", pointData.node.bcpOutData);
                [moc deleteObject:pointData.node.bcpOutData];
                pointData.node = nil;

            }
            NSLog(@"deleting originData: %@", pointData.node.bcpOutData);
            [moc deleteObject:pointData];
            pointData.node = nil;

        } else { //delete just object

            [moc deleteObject:pointData];
            pointData.node = nil;
        }
        NSLog(@"node: %@", node);   
    }


    NSMutableArray * contoursToDelete = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (TPNode * node in nodesToDelete) {

        if (node.contour.nodes.count == 1) {
            [contoursToDelete addObject:node.contour];
        }
        [moc deleteObject:node];
    }

    for (TPContour * contour in contoursToDelete) {
        [moc deleteObject:contour];
    }
    [points didChangeValueForKey:@"arrangedObjects"];
    [undoManager endUndoGrouping];
}
```

Listing after try to delete *origin*:

```
2013-02-03 12:11:34.849 AlwaysSmooth[42786:403] PointData <TPPointData: 0x105c06400> (entity: PointData; id: 0x100133810 <x-coredata://8E705B64-CB39-4FBD-B296-936E70835DC8/PointData/p327> ; data: {
    node = "0x100133830 <x-coredata://8E705B64-CB39-4FBD-B296-936E70835DC8/Node/p328>";
    x = "215.5";
    y = "550.1667";
})
2013-02-03 12:11:34.850 AlwaysSmooth[42786:403] PointData.node = <TPNode: 0x105c13250> (entity: Node; id: 0x100133830 <x-coredata://8E705B64-CB39-4FBD-B296-936E70835DC8/Node/p328> ; data: {
    attribute = nil;
    bcpIn = "(...not nil..)";
    bcpInData = "0x1001337b0 <x-coredata://8E705B64-CB39-4FBD-B296-936E70835DC8/PointData/p326>";
    bcpOut = "(...not nil..)";
    bcpOutData = "0x100133640 <x-coredata://8E705B64-CB39-4FBD-B296-936E70835DC8/PointData/p329>";
    contour = "0x1001c8c20 <x-coredata://8E705B64-CB39-4FBD-B296-936E70835DC8/Contour/p282>";
    next = "(...not nil..)";
    originData = "0x100133810 <x-coredata://8E705B64-CB39-4FBD-B296-936E70835DC8/PointData/p327>";
    prev = "(...not nil..)";
    smooth = 1;
    type = 2;
})
2013-02-03 12:11:34.851 AlwaysSmooth[42786:403] deleting bcpInData: <TPPointData: 0x100183d70> (entity: PointData; id: 0x1001337b0 <x-coredata://8E705B64-CB39-4FBD-B296-936E70835DC8/PointData/p326> ; data: {
    node = "0x100133830 <x-coredata://8E705B64-CB39-4FBD-B296-936E70835DC8/Node/p328>";
    x = "301.4023";
    y = "544.7839";
})
2013-02-03 12:11:34.853 AlwaysSmooth[42786:403] deleting originData: (null)
2013-02-03 12:11:34.854 AlwaysSmooth[42786:403] node: <TPNode: 0x105c13250> (entity: Node; id: 0x100133830 <x-coredata://8E705B64-CB39-4FBD-B296-936E70835DC8/Node/p328> ; data: {
    attribute = nil;
    bcpIn = "(...not nil..)";
    bcpInData = "0x1001337b0 <x-coredata://8E705B64-CB39-4FBD-B296-936E70835DC8/PointData/p326>";
    bcpOut = "(...not nil..)";
    bcpOutData = "0x100133640 <x-coredata://8E705B64-CB39-4FBD-B296-936E70835DC8/PointData/p329>";
    contour = "0x1001c8c20 <x-coredata://8E705B64-CB39-4FBD-B296-936E70835DC8/Contour/p282>";
    next = "(...not nil..)";
    originData = nil;
    prev = "(...not nil..)";
    smooth = 1;
    type = 2;
})
```

Why it does not even try to delete *bcpOutData*? *originData* is null before deletion. After deletion *bcpInData* and *bcpOutData* still exist in node object.
Undo is still possible.

When I try to delete only *bcpInData* or *bcpOutData* code deletes only *originData* again:

```
2013-02-03 12:29:13.526 AlwaysSmooth[42786:403] PointData <TPPointData: 0x100183d70> (entity: PointData; id: 0x1001337b0 <x-coredata://8E705B64-CB39-4FBD-B296-936E70835DC8/PointData/p326> ; data: {
    node = "0x100133830 <x-coredata://8E705B64-CB39-4FBD-B296-936E70835DC8/Node/p328>";
    x = "301.4023";
    y = "544.7839";
})
2013-02-03 12:29:13.527 AlwaysSmooth[42786:403] PointData.node = <TPNode: 0x105c13250> (entity: Node; id: 0x100133830 <x-coredata://8E705B64-CB39-4FBD-B296-936E70835DC8/Node/p328> ; data: {
    attribute = nil;
    bcpIn = "(...not nil..)";
    bcpInData = "0x1001337b0 <x-coredata://8E705B64-CB39-4FBD-B296-936E70835DC8/PointData/p326>";
    bcpOut = "(...not nil..)";
    bcpOutData = "0x100133640 <x-coredata://8E705B64-CB39-4FBD-B296-936E70835DC8/PointData/p329>";
    contour = "0x1001c8c20 <x-coredata://8E705B64-CB39-4FBD-B296-936E70835DC8/Contour/p282>";
    next = "(...not nil..)";
    originData = "0x100133810 <x-coredata://8E705B64-CB39-4FBD-B296-936E70835DC8/PointData/p327>";
    prev = "(...not nil..)";
    smooth = 1;
    type = 2;
})
2013-02-03 12:29:13.529 AlwaysSmooth[42786:403] node: <TPNode: 0x105c13250> (entity: Node; id: 0x100133830 <x-coredata://8E705B64-CB39-4FBD-B296-936E70835DC8/Node/p328> ; data: {
    attribute = nil;
    bcpIn = "(...not nil..)";
    bcpInData = "0x1001337b0 <x-coredata://8E705B64-CB39-4FBD-B296-936E70835DC8/PointData/p326>";
    bcpOut = "(...not nil..)";
    bcpOutData = "0x100133640 <x-coredata://8E705B64-CB39-4FBD-B296-936E70835DC8/PointData/p329>";
    contour = "0x1001c8c20 <x-coredata://8E705B64-CB39-4FBD-B296-936E70835DC8/Contour/p282>";
    next = "(...not nil..)";
    originData = nil;
    prev = "(...not nil..)";
    smooth = 1;
    type = 2;
})
```

Any help?

Comment: How did you set the delete rules of your relations?

Comment: I tried with _nullify_, _cascade_, _denny_ and _no action_ in both directions. Nothing changes.

Comment: Please write your entire question at the top, then break it down into sections, with the code below it. It's easier for someone to read the whole question to get the idea of the problem you're having and then to look for details rather than just getting one piece at a time.

Comment: Better? English is not my native language, writing and thinking in english is always bit painful ;)

Answer (score 0):

BcpInData and BcpOutData was selected in points controller. It was enough to 
`[points removeSelectedObjects:@[pointData]];` before deletion.